Include a Chinese version for the post notices
Recently we've had some new users who provided Chinese answers to our questions and this is good. But some of these answers were too short or lacked something else, so I added post notices or directly commented.
Sometimes, though, the fact that they answer in Chinese might mean one thing: they don't know English that well.
Therefore the mods of this site (xiaohouzi79, Don Kirkby and me) have been thinking of doing some changes to the post notices. Post notices are those yellow things you see under posts that let the author know that there is something wrong with the post. If you want to propose a translation, this is the text of the post notices. If someone already provided a good translation, please try to work on that.
Proposal:  The best idea would be to include 3 additional choices which basically provide the same post notices, simply translated in Chinese.

citation needed
This post does not cite any references or sources. Please help improve this article by adding citations to reliable sources. Unsourced material may be challenged and removed.
current event
Post is related to a rapidly changing event.
insufficient explanation
We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer: please explain why you're recommending it as a solution. Answers that don't explain anything will be deleted. See [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective (this is a link, ignore this)] for more information.


Great idea! May I propose to add Chinese translations to the title and welcome panel as well.

How about this:
[需要引证]
此贴没有提供任何参考或来源。请帮助改善答案并引用可靠资料来源以免引起争议而被删除。
[当前事项]
此贴与快速变化的事项有关。
[不够详细]
我们需要较详细的答案，包括解释和一些上下文 — 不要只给一句答案。肤浅的答案将被删除。
I don't quite understand the second notice but have translated it nevertheless. Please feel free to improve on it and correct any errors you find.

Eh, my Chinese level is kind of basic so I'm asking the community for help, otherwise I would've proposed myself. If you want to understand more, read What does the “Current event” post notice mean?. :)

@Alenanno, I have read that but can't think of a scenario where it would be applicable. Seems like meta is very quiet.
